# Are they true these generalizations from matrices to operators about functional calculus?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

**Motivation**: If we have some real function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix such that $\lambda_i \in I$ for all $1\leqslant i \leqslant n$, then we define $$f(D)=\operatorname{diag}(f(\lambda_1),\ldots, f(\lambda_n)).$$
If $A$ is Hermitian matrix whose eingenvalues $\lambda_j$ are in $I$, we than can choose unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=UDU^*$, where $D$ is diagonal, and then we define $f(A)=Uf(D)U^*$.

**My question**: suppose that now $A$ is some self-adjoint operator on some separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$. I know that for continuous function $f$ (but this can be done for Borel measurable function, but we will stick with continuous functions) defined on some interval $I$ and self-adjoint (but it's also true for normal operators) operator $A \in B(H)$ such that $\sigma(A) \subset I$ we define 
$$f(A) = \int_{\sigma(A)} f(t)\, dE(t)$$
where $E$ is spectral measure associated with $A$, that is $A=\displaystyle\int_{\sigma(A)} t\, dE(t)$.

I am wondering, if we have some operator $T \in B(H \oplus H)$ defined with $T=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operator such that $\sigma(A),\sigma(B) \subset I$ and if $f$ is continuous function on $I$, do we then have 
$$f(T)=\begin{bmatrix}f(A) & 0 \\ 0 & f(B)\end{bmatrix}$$
Also, if $X=U^* T U$ where $U$ is some unitary operator, do we then have $f(X)=U^* f(T) U$?

Basically, I am wondering are they true generalizations from matrix case? If yes (which I strongly believes), how can we prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The functional calculus preserves approximation by polynomials. So, from 
$$
T^n=\begin{bmatrix}A^n&0\\0&B^n\end{bmatrix},
$$
you get that 
$$
p(T)=\begin{bmatrix}p(A)&0\\0&p(B)\end{bmatrix}
$$
for any polynomial $p$. Now using a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to $f$, you get that 
$$
f(T)=\begin{bmatrix}f(A)&0\\0&f(B)\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For a unitary, a similar reasoning applies. You have $X^n=UT^nU^*$ for all $n$, so $p(X)=Up(T)U^*$ for all polynomials, and by taking limits you deduce that $f(X)=Uf(T)U^*$.

Comment: I want to be 100% sure that I understand all. First, do we that formula have from $T^n$ have from $TT = diag (A,B) diag (A,B) = diag(A^2,B^2)$,and then by induction for all $n$? If yes, then I see why that formula for $p(T)$ is also valid. Then, can you show me why from uniformly converges we have that? I know that is right, but can you show step by step how we get that? I suppose we are using here DTC and that $\sigma(T)$ is compact? Thanks.

Comment: Yes to your first question. As for the second one, you can approximate your continuous function uniformly by polynomials; as long as your measure is finite (which it is, in this case), the limit of the integrals is the integral of the limit.

Comment: I will show you my attempt here: let $p_n \rightrightarrows f$ and $p_n(T)=\begin{bmatrix} p_n(A) & 0 \\ 0 & p_n(B)\end{bmatrix}$. Also, $p_n(T) = \int_{\sigma(T)} p_n(t) \, dE(t)$. Then $\langle \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(T) g,g\rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle  p_n(T) g,g\rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\sigma(T)} p_n(t) d\mu_{g}(t)$ $= \int_{\sigma(T)} \lim_{n \to \infty}  p_n(t) d\mu_{g}(t) $ $= \int_{\sigma(T)} f(t) d\mu_g(t)=\langle f(T) g,g\rangle$ for all $g \in H$ because 
$\mu_g(\sigma(T)) = \langle E(\sigma(T))g,g\rangle \leq \|g\|^2<\infty$

Comment: and $p_n(t)$ is bounded on $\sigma(T)$ as continuous function on compact set, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(T) = f(T)$, that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \begin{bmatrix} p_n(A) & 0 \\ 0 & p_n(B)\end{bmatrix} = f(T).$ Now I am wondering why $\lim_{n \to \infty} \begin{bmatrix} p_n(A) & 0 \\ 0 & p_n(B)\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(A) & 0 \\ 0 & \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(B)\end{bmatrix}$? I am not familiar with that (to be honest, I work more with operators than matrices)

Comment: Writing limits is never a good practice. To prove limit equalities, you deal with inequalities. The key piece of information here is that, for a direct sum, $\|A\oplus B\|=\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}$. The block-diagonal matrix is a direct sum.

Comment: I think I got it. Let see. $\| f(A) \oplus f(B) - p_n(A) \oplus p_n(B) \|\ =\| (f(A)-p_n(A)) \oplus (f(B)-p_n(B))\|$ $ = \max\{\| f(A)-p_n(A)\|,\| f(B)-p_n(B)\|\}\to 0$ because $p_n(A) \to f(A)$ and $p_n(B) \to f(B)$ (which can be proved in similar way like for operator $T$), so $f(T) = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(T) = f(A) \oplus f(B)$. Is know everything all right?

Comment: Exactly. ${\ \ }$

Comment: Great! I am really happy! One way to see that $\|A\oplus B\|=\max\{\|A\|,\|B\|\}$ is that $s(A \oplus B) = (s_1(A),s_1(B),s_2(A),s_2(B),\ldots)$, so $\| A \oplus B\| = \max s(A \oplus B) = \max \{ \|A\|, \|B\|\}$. But I think this is overkill, or maybe not? 

And now I can truly to give you +1 and to accept your answer!

Comment: It is probably overkill, one can do it directly using the definition of the operator norm.

Comment: Okay. Thank you again Martin, you really helped me!

Comment: My pleasure. $| $